# eclipse intellisense with Android SDK

Tags: android

I am using the latest Android SDK (2.1-update1 - Level 7) but I am finding that the intellisense is rather poor in Eclipse. Is it just me or is anyone else experiencing intellisense issues with Android SDK?

Comment: Have you used Eclipse before?  Perhaps you are just not used to the differences between Visual Studio and Eclipse?  (IntelliSense is Microsoft's autocompletion implementation, Eclipse doesn't use it)

Comment: Well...when I say Intellisense, I just mean the suggestions box that is supposed to popup when you press Ctrl+Space after you start typing.

Comment: Is there a specific problem that you have?

Comment: works pretty well for me!

Comment: Specifically, suppose I type - 

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

and then I start typing 
    layout.

and then I hit Ctrl+Space, I expect to get a suggestion box with all the available methods for the layout object but I get nada.

Comment: Being a .NET develper myself, I understand your issues. Eclipse generally has the same features, but are handled a bit differently. In Eclipse, auto-activation requires a trigger. By default it is the "." character. In Visual Stuido, auto-activation does not require a trigger. So when you type "l", the popup appears automatically. In Eclipse, if you want to see suggestions before typing "layout.", you have to hit [Ctrl-Space] to see the suggestions for the current context. The settings that control this behavior can be found at: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist

Answer (score 4):

Configure Eclipse’s content assist, go “Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced“. Make sure “Other Java Proposals” is ticked.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with ADT, here is how I solved it:

1. Go to:
   Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced
2. Then check everything that says Java in it.
3. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

Also here is it no problem. If I write

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
```

And then

```
layout.
```

There are alot of suggestions. You have to type till you receive the dot. After the dot you'll get those suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

actually you shouldn't even need to press Ctrl+Space - the suggestion should come up after typing the "." as well

just to make sure: are you aware of the fact that you need to install the ADT Plugin for Eclipse additionally to the Android SDK when you develop in Eclipse?

[ADT Plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Answer (score 0):

[try this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_enable_code_completion_to_be_activated_as_I_type_like_how_it_works_in_Visual_Studio.3F): instead of triggering just on the "." it triggers on all letters

Answer (score 0):

if none of those works try this:
Window -> Preferences -> General Keys
in "type filter text" type : content assist
select and change its binding into any key you want

i made it into CTR+TAB in my case

Maybe your PC uses CTR+SPACE to other programs

CHEERS